# C++ MSVC/GCC compilation issue with member function specialization of derived class

Tags: c++, templates, derived-class, specialization, member-functions

Why does the following piece of code compile with gcc (4.6.3) but when using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 it results in an error that the second member function `SomeFunction` is already defined or declared? What do I need to change such that this example works with both gcc and the Microsoft compiler?

Thanks very much for your help.

```
template <bool B = false>
class Base {
public:
    Base() {};
    ~Base() {};
    template <bool U> struct i2t{};
    typedef i2t<B> SomeType;
    void Test1(i2t<true>) {
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    }
    void Test1(i2t<false>) {
        std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
    }
    void Test() {
        Test1(SomeType());
    }
};

template <class N=Base<false> >
class Derived : public N {
public:
    Derived() {};
    ~Derived() {};
    void SomeFunction(typename N::template i2t<true>) {
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    }
    void SomeFunction(typename N::template i2t<false>) {
        std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
    }
    void Caller() {
        SomeFunction(typename N::SomeType());
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    class Base<false> test;
    test.Test();
    class Base<true> test1;
    test1.Test();
    class Derived<Base<false> > test2;
    test2.Caller();
    class Derived<Base<true> > test3;
    test3.Caller();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/567070/bogus-c2535-error-when-overloading-method-name-with-dependent-typedef

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, this link answers the first part of my question.

Comment: The guy put in his email address, I'd recommend you use it :)

Comment: The link does not work.